# How to split a dataframe in R

Tags: r, split

I have a 10 x 1 dataframe where each cell contains 10 numbers separated by an empty space. How would I split this dataframe so I can obtain one number per cell (i.e a 10 x 10 dataframe) ? I have tried with the split and separate functions but with no success.
Thank you

**My data:**

```
structure(list(x = structure(1:2, .Label = c("668 1.000 1 14.8876 1 3.474638 3.5887 0.2150 0.348 -0.110 0.992 1 27.7460 1 20.4108 1 6.722 1 112.68000 0", 
"686 1.500 1 14.9045 1 3.475565 3.5868 0.3391 -0.064 0.115 1.487 1 27.7420 1 20.4042 1 6.722 1 112.71500 0"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to show a small reproducible example i.e `dput(head(yourdata, 20))`

Comment: The first two rows look like this (I apologize for the lack of formatting: "        668       1.000  1     14.8876  1    3.474638      3.5887      0.2150       0.348      -0.110       0.992  1     27.7460  1     20.4108  1       6.722  1   112.68000  0 ", 
"        686       1.500  1     14.9045  1    3.475565      3.5868      0.3391      -0.064       0.115       1.487  1     27.7420  1     20.4042  1       6.722  1   112.71500  0 ",

Comment: Based on your input, the `read.table` is working fine.  But, there are 20 entries instead of 10.  i.e. `read.table(text = v1, header = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `separate` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df, 1, paste0("Col", 1:10), sep = "\\s+", convert = TRUE)
```

With `convert = TRUE`, all output columns get converted to numeric type.

**Output:**

```
     Col1 Col2   Col3    Col4    Col5     Col6   Col7   Col8    Col9  Col10
1 668.000  1.0  1.000 14.8876  1.0000 3.474638 3.5887 0.2150   0.348 -0.110
2   0.992  1.0 27.746  1.0000 20.4108 1.000000 6.7220 1.0000 112.680  0.000
3 686.000  1.5  1.000 14.9045  1.0000 3.475565 3.5868 0.3391  -0.064  0.115
4   1.487  1.0 27.742  1.0000 20.4042 1.000000 6.7220 1.0000 112.715  0.000
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("668 1.000 1 14.8876 1 3.474638 3.5887 0.2150 0.348 -0.110", 
                       "0.992 1 27.7460 1 20.4108 1 6.722 1 112.68000 0", 
                       "686 1.500 1 14.9045 1 3.475565 3.5868 0.3391 -0.064 0.115", 
                       "1.487 1 27.7420 1 20.4042 1 6.722 1 112.71500 0"))
```

Comment: @Blue Please note that although you get 10 columns in the final output, 10 numbers were discarded because your sample data has 20 numbers per row. See my sample data which has 10 numbers per row. Of course, you can always change the third `into` argument to accommodate for more output columns.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `read.table` from `base R` to separate the column ('Column' - change it to the actual column name and the object name ('df1'))

```
df2 <- read.table(text = as.character(df$x), header = FALSE)
df2
#       V1  V2     V3      V4      V5       V6     V7     V8      V9    V10
#1 668.000 1.0  1.000 14.8876  1.0000 3.474638 3.5887 0.2150   0.348 -0.110
#2   0.992 1.0 27.746  1.0000 20.4108 1.000000 6.7220 1.0000 112.680  0.000
#3 686.000 1.5  1.000 14.9045  1.0000 3.475565 3.5868 0.3391  -0.064  0.115
#4   1.487 1.0 27.742  1.0000 20.4042 1.000000 6.7220 1.0000 112.715  0.000
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), 
.Label = c("0.992 1 27.7460 1 20.4108 1 6.722 1 112.68000 0", 
"1.487 1 27.7420 1 20.4042 1 6.722 1 112.71500 0", 
"668 1.000 1 14.8876 1 3.474638 3.5887 0.2150 0.348 -0.110", 
"686 1.500 1 14.9045 1 3.475565 3.5868 0.3391 -0.064 0.115"), 
class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but I get the following error: Error in textConnection(text, encoding = "UTF-8") : invalid 'text' argument

Comment: @Blue Can you add the `encoding = "UTF-8"` in the `read.table` and then run it

Comment: Yes. Here's what I got: df2 <- read.table(text = rawdata$V1, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")

Comment: @Blue Okay, without a small reproducible example with `dput` it is not clear what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

With the function `separate()`, you can specify the names of the new columns and the separator.

```
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(col1 = c('668 1.000 1 14.8876 1 3.474638'))
df %>% separate('col1', c('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6'), sep = ' ')

   a1    a2 a3      a4 a5       a6
1 668 1.000  1 14.8876  1 3.474638
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: I didn't see your answer. It's the same.